# Password Hash returns 0 in Signup Form

Tags: php

So in my PHP file for a signup form, the password_hash returns a 0 into the database. Is that normal? Earlier, when I created a similar signup form, the text in the password column was a jumble of letters and numbers, so I am unsure if this is correct. Moreover, when creating the login form, the password always returns false, even when I am certain that the password is correct.

To put it simply, is the reason that my PHP login form is not validating a correct password because of an incorrect hashing in the signup that hashes the password as "0" or of another error in my code?

Below is the relevant section of the PHP code for the signup form:

```
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);
//hashing password
$hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

//add user to db
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, class, email, username, password) VALUES ('$name', '$class', '$email', '$uid', '$hashedPwd');";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
header("Location: ../welcome.php?signup=success");
exit();
```

Below are the relevant sections of the login form, in which the password always returns false:

```
$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$uid'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($resultCheck < 1) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=user");
    exit();
}else{
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        //De-hashing the password
        $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['password']);
        if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
            header("Location: ../index.php?login=pass");
            exit();
        } elseif($hashedPwdCheck == true){
            //logged in here
            $_SESSION['u_name'] = $row['name'];
            $_SESSION['u_class'] = $row['class'];
            $_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['email'];
            $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row['username'];
            header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check $pwd value after `$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);` ?

Comment: Check what value is in DB, check what you send via POST, print out `$pwd` and `$row['password']`

Comment: As mentioned by jkt you should ***not*** be using `mysqli_real_escape_string` with password fields. Instead you should look into **SQL Prepared Statements**

Comment: The 0 you get from password_hash is a false to say something did go wrong, are you sure $pwd is not empty? You need to check that you actually did get a password before hashing it. I would also have removed the escaping of the password so you don't have to include that after moving on to parametarized queries in the future, since you are not inserting the password but a hash of it

Answer (score 0):

Why are you use mysql_real_escape_string for clear posted data?
First of all, check posted password is correct. If ok, then make hash, aftet escape for insert query.

Comment: Do not escape posted string for verify. Because the query results are not escaped string, just the value.